# scope of definition, using notes in beamer

Tags: beamer

I get undefined control sequence \thenextitem for this piece of code.   I think it's something to do with the scope of the definition, but I don't want to make it global because I want to carry this out multiple times, for each list item.  Any ideas how to properly do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
            \def\thenextitem{
               text for the next item
            }
         \begin{itemize}
            \item<1->\thenextitem
            \note[item]<1->{\thenextitem..and some extra text}
         \end{itemize}
      \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make it globally, you could restrict the definition to a group around the frame and the note frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

    {
        \def\thenextitem{
            text for the next item
        }
    \begin{frame}

       \begin{itemize}
          \item<1->\thenextitem
          \note[item]<1->{\thenextitem..and some extra text}
       \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
  }

 \end{document}
```

But if you want to use something similar multiple times within a single frame, things gets more complicate. Maybe another approach would be easier:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\newcommand{\mynote}[2]{%
    \item #1
    \note[item]{#1 #2}
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
       \begin{itemize}
          \mynote{text for main and notes}{additional notes}
       \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]